# Track ArUco marker in gray scale OpenCV image?

Tags: opencv, aruco

I want to use ArUco marker to do AR and I want to know if I can track the ArUco marker in a grays scale OpenCV image?

Thanks.

YL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Aruco are able to detect gray image.

```
frame = cv2.imread("aruco_captured_image.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
aruco_dict = aruco.Dictionary_get(aruco.DICT_6X6_250)
parameters = aruco.DetectorParameters_create()
corners, ids, rejectedImgPoints = aruco.detectMarkers(gray, aruco_dict, parameters=parameters)
```

This worked fine for aruco detection as a I passed the single captured frame.